# onClick event open page then load function

Tags: jquery, web, onclick, href

On **#page2**, I have an hidden content triggered by the function **openContent()**.

On **#page1**, I'd like a href tag to load **#page2** then load the **openContent()** function.

I tried to create a onClick event that would do both on **#page1** but it doesn't work.

I'm new to jQuery and I must have it all mixed up.

Thanks

Comment: Do you always want `openContent()` to run when opening page2, or only when linked to from page1?

Comment: Only when linked from #page1. On #page2 I have a specific onclick event that opens it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Page 1**: `<a href="page2.html#open">Page 2</a>`

**Page 2**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  if(window.location.hash == "open") {
    openContent();
  }
});
```

Comment: What if the #open div is hidden at first?

Comment: I thought the "#open" from page 1 was a div. In fact, it seems like I misunderstood the hash propriety. I need to play with it a bit, get back to you soon.

Comment: Seems to be a good solution but cannot get it to work. I made a small test here (http://tinyurl.com/abzchfw), maybe you can point to me what I did wrong. When you click on the black box, #page2 is called and the bigger black box should become red.

Comment: Got it! Forgot about #open for window.location.hash.A real thank you man!

Comment: Glad you got it working. Don't forget to accept the answer. :)

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you call your function in #page2 onload

```
<body onload="openContent()">
```

Comment: Because I have openContent1(), onpenContent2(), onpenContent3() (up to five). #page2 displays five different links, #page1 has them too in its footer.

Comment: P.S: you could use like this if you want onload="openContent();openContent1();openContent2()";

Answer (score 0):

If you need to do this with transient content, or by a trigger from the second page, you can use jQuery's .on() to attach a handler for these types of scenarios.

http://api.jquery.com/on/

A simple example (from the wiki):

```
$("#dataTable tbody tr").on("click", function(event){
  alert($(this).text());
});
```

You would use this to wire up a click event, for example, to any `tr` that exists on the page at any time (doesn't need to exist).

You could use this strategy to wire up your on click for page 2 *on* page 1, then it will only take effect when it's loaded via page 1.

Cheers.

Comment: Hi James, I managed with @Samsquanch solution, didn't had the chance to try yours. Thanks again.

Comment: No worries, keep jQuery.on() in your back pocket, it's definitely worth learning.